# PyTorch model training is suddenly super slow

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, gpu

I'm using PyTorch (version 1.8.1) to train a set of 40 LSTMs on a set of speech data using a TitanV GPU with Ubuntu 18.04. I setup the code so that each LSTM is trained until it converges, so each LSTM converges on a different epoch. I'm using DataLoaders with a batch size of 16 and num_workers set to 4. The first few epochs lasted ~50 minutes, while the most recent epochs lasted ~10 minutes since most of the models have converged (see below). However, the current epoch started at 06:29 and is still running, but I would have expected this epoch to finish long ago.

I know the code is still running since nvidia-smi shows python as using > 6MiB of memory (see below), which is normally the amount of memory that is used.

What might be causing this problem?

As a side note, one thing I noticed was the message "System program problem detected", although I am not sure whether this is related.

```
INFO:root:Time: 05/24/21 16:24:40, Epoch: 1
INFO:root:Time: 05/24/21 17:16:19, Epoch: 2
INFO:root:Time: 05/24/21 18:08:10, Epoch: 3
INFO:root:Time: 05/24/21 18:59:52, Epoch: 4
INFO:root:Time: 05/24/21 19:51:41, Epoch: 5
INFO:root:Time: 05/24/21 20:43:21, Epoch: 6
INFO:root:Time: 05/24/21 21:35:09, Epoch: 7
INFO:root:Time: 05/24/21 22:26:56, Epoch: 8
INFO:root:Time: 05/24/21 23:18:40, Epoch: 9
INFO:root:Time: 05/25/21 00:10:27, Epoch: 10
INFO:root:Time: 05/25/21 01:02:24, Epoch: 11
INFO:root:Time: 05/25/21 01:54:16, Epoch: 12
INFO:root:Time: 05/25/21 02:44:33, Epoch: 13
INFO:root:Time: 05/25/21 03:34:58, Epoch: 14
INFO:root:Time: 05/25/21 04:20:09, Epoch: 15
INFO:root:Time: 05/25/21 04:59:01, Epoch: 16
INFO:root:Time: 05/25/21 05:28:44, Epoch: 17
INFO:root:Time: 05/25/21 05:50:44, Epoch: 18
INFO:root:Time: 05/25/21 06:08:50, Epoch: 19
INFO:root:Time: 05/25/21 06:20:41, Epoch: 20
INFO:root:Time: 05/25/21 06:29:32, Epoch: 21
```

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.73.01    Driver Version: 460.73.01    CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  TITAN V             Off  | 00000000:03:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 28%   39C    P8    24W / 250W |   6751MiB / 12065MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1293      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 18MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1509      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               73MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3340      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                111MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3534      G   ...mviewer/tv_bin/TeamViewer       27MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3572      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               34MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4406      G   ...f_4086.log --shared-files        6MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     11837      C   python                           6471MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

EDIT 1: This is how I am implementing the DataLoaders. The below code also shows a simplified version of my train function.

```
    training_set = Dataset(train_list, conf_dict, le)
    training_generator = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(training_set, batch_size=conf_dict["batch_size"],
                                                     num_workers=4, collate_fn=collate_fn, shuffle=True)
    valid_set = Dataset(valid_list, conf_dict, le)
    valid_generator = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(valid_set, batch_size=conf_dict["batch_size"],
                                                  num_workers=4, collate_fn=collate_fn, shuffle=True)
```

```
class Dataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, file_list, conf_dict, le=None):
        self.file_list = file_list
        self.conf_dict = conf_dict
        self.le = le

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.file_list)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        # Read single feature file                                                                                                                                                                          
        X, y, p = read_feat_file(self.file_list[index], self.conf_dict)
                                                                                                                                                   
        if bool(self.le):
            p = self.le.transform(p).astype('long')

        return X, y, p
```

```
def collate_fn(batch):
    """                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    Used to collate multiple files for dataloader                                                                                                                                                           
    """
    X_batch, y_batch, p_batch = zip(*batch)
    X_batch = list(X_batch)
    y_batch = list(y_batch)
    p_batch = list(p_batch)

    # Get maximum sequence length                                                                                                                                                                           
    seq_lens = np.array(list(map(lambda a: len(a), y_batch)), dtype='int')
    max_seq_len = np.max(seq_lens)

    # Apply -1 padding                                                                                                                                                                                      
    for file_idx in range(len(y_batch)):
        if np.shape(y_batch[file_idx])[0] < max_seq_len:
            pad_len = max_seq_len - np.shape(y_batch[file_idx])[0]
            X_batch[file_idx] = np.concatenate((X_batch[file_idx], -np.ones((pad_len, np.shape(X_batch[file_idx])[1]), dtype='float32')), axis=0)
            y_batch[file_idx] = np.concatenate((y_batch[file_idx], -np.ones((pad_len, np.shape(y_batch[file_idx])[1]), dtype='float32')), axis=0)
            p_batch[file_idx] = np.concatenate((p_batch[file_idx], np.zeros((pad_len,), dtype='long')), axis=0)

    # Convert to np.array                                                                                                                                                                                   
    X_batch = np.array(X_batch)
    y_batch = np.array(y_batch)
    p_batch = np.array(p_batch)

    return X_batch, y_batch, p_batch
```

```
def train(experts, optimizers, le, conf_dict, train_generator):                                                                                                                                                                                       
    device = get_device()

    for X_batch, y_batch, p_batch in train_generator:                                                                                                                                                                                     
        X_batch = (torch.from_numpy(X_batch)).to(device)
        y_batch = (torch.from_numpy(y_batch)).to(device)
        p_batch = (torch.from_numpy(p_batch)).to(device)

        for key in list(experts.keys()):
            experts[key].train()
            optimizers[key].zero_grad()
                                                                                                                                        
            mask = (p_batch == ((le.transform([key])).astype('long')[0]))
            mask = mask.reshape(mask.size()[0], mask.size()[1], 1)
            loss_mask = mask * (y_batch != -1)
                                                                                                                                    
            if torch.sum(loss_mask) > 0:                                                                                                                                                                            
                train_outputs = experts[key](X_batch)

                # Simplified loss calculation
                loss = torch.sum(loss_mask * F.mse_loss(y_pred, y_true, reduction='none'))                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                         
                loss.backward()
                optimizers[key].step()
```

Comment: It's very hard for anyone to give you advice on the matter without seeing the code. My guess is that you've introduced a bottleneck somewhere or there's a race condition. I suspect the issue is most likely to be found in the DataLoader.

Comment: I edited the post to give more detail on how I'm implementing DataLoaders and my train function. Does this help?

Comment: nvidia-smi shows GPU utilization is 0 and temps are very low indicating the GPU is idle. The process is still alive (hence memory still allocated) but seems to have stopped doing any processing.

Comment: what happens if `torch.sum(loss) >= 0`? We're still not seing the full loop.

Comment: Edited to show simplified loss calculation. @Ælex I'm using MSE loss, so `torch.sum(loss)` is always `>= 0`.